# having issue with MANIFEST.MF in jar

Tags: java, manifest

I have created jar for my project,I am having problem with MANIFEST.MF.
structure of my MANIFEST.MF is as follows:

```
------------------------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager
Class-Path: /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
----------------------------
```

when I run this using command:

```
>>java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments...
```

then its working properly.....
but I dont want the full Class-Path name.

So when structure of my MANIFEST.MF is as follows: 
and I want this to run using following Class-Path:

```
---------------------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager
Class-Path: lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
----------------------------
```

and now when I run this using command:

```
>>java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments...
```

then it is showing error:---

```
---Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
    at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more
```

Please tell me solution for that.....

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the required library is not on the actual classpath. [Here it says:](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html)

> The URLs in the Class-Path header are given relative to the URL of the JAR file of the applet or application.

So at my understandig, java now looks for the hector library (only) at this location:

```
/usr/local/bin/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

---

Note, that if you execute java with the `-jar` option, the classpath entries are taken from the manefest **only**, additional entries in `-cp` or `$CLASSPATH` are ignored.